# SOQL Query: Stored XSS Error

Tags: salesforce

I have given my code for Security code Scanner but it is given the following error due to

> Query: Stored XSS

My query is like this.

```
loan=Database.query('SELECT Name,fintechLLC__Application__c ,fintechLLC__Legal_Corporate_Name__c,fintechLLC__Last_Month_Trans__c,   fintechLLC__X2_Month_ago_Trans_del__c,fintechLLC__X3_Month_ago_Trans__c,CreatedDate,fintechLLC__Monthly_Ending_Bal__c,Max_Rate__c,fintechLLC__Term__c,fintechLLC__Funding_Amount__c,fintechLLC__Business_DBA_Name__c,fintechLLC__Credit_Score__c, fintechLLC__Business_DBA_Years_in_Business__c,fintechLLC__Avg_Daily_Bank_Bal__c FROM fintechLLC__Loan__c where id=\''+loanId+'\'');
```

Kindly help me in this

Answer (score 0):

In your Dynamic query, you should use String.escapeSingleQuotes to prevent SOQL injection.

Go up the path for the variable loadId, and make sure that in your visualforce page it's wrapped properly either by JSENCODE or HTMLENCODE - which depends on how you use it.

```
  loan=Database.query('SELECT Name,fintechLLC__Application__c ,fintechLLC__Legal_Corporate_Name__c,fintechLLC__Last_Month_Trans__c,   fintechLLC__X2_Month_ago_Trans_del__c,fintechLLC__X3_Month_ago_Trans__c,CreatedDate,fintechLLC__Monthly_Ending_Bal__c,Max_Rate__c,fintechLLC__Term__c,fintechLLC__Funding_Amount__c,fintechLLC__Business_DBA_Name__c,fintechLLC__Credit_Score__c, fintechLLC__Business_DBA_Years_in_Business__c,fintechLLC__Avg_Daily_Bank_Bal__c FROM fintechLLC__Loan__c where id=\''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(loanId)+'\'');
```